# SQL query sums data from one col by distinct in another. Distincts stored in table as integers with name in another table. How do I output real name?

Tags: php, sql

As per the title, I'm running the following SQL query:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Policy Area`, SUM(`Sum Approved`) as `Sum Approved`
FROM Contracts GROUP BY `Policy Area`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Policy Area:". $row["Policy Area"]. " Sum: ". $row["Sum Approved"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Simple enough, and I'm going to be coding it up so it essentially creates a bar chat showing percentage spend by policy area. However, the Policy Area is stored in the Contracts Table as an ID, which itself relates to another Table where the actual name is.

Obviously, I would much rather have the full name as opposed to the ID, but what's the best way of accomplishing?

Is it simply a case of building the required extra SQL queries to the Policy Area table into the while loop?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` to the other table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join to the other table (assumed to be named Policy here) and include that in the rollup:

```
select c.PolicyArea, p.PolicyName, SUM(c.SumApproved) as SumApproved
from Contracts inner join Policy on c.PolicyArea = p.PolicyArea    
GROUP by c.PolicyArea, p.PolicyName
```

This will give you 1 resultset with columns of "Policy Area", "Policy Name", and "SumApproved".

I'm making up the other table name and fields where the Policy name is decoded from the Id, as well as the JOIN, but you get the idea.